# Add support for LTI 1.1.2 tool provider

Tags: canvas, moodle, lti, blackboard

Our e-learning application as a tool provider supports LTI 1.0 standards, Since IMS global stoped the support for LTI1.0 so we are planning to upgrade to immediate supported version which is LTi 1.1.2.
I am finding default to get some simulator or the tool consumer to test my application. Someone suggest me any Tool consumer application which supports the LTI1.1.2 version.

Comment: Brightspace by D2L supports making LTI 1.1.2 requests. However, I'm not sure they have a free/trial version; you may need to set up a contract with them to gain access to their tool consumer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an IMS member you could use their [tool certification test suite](https://www.imsglobal.org/lti-certification-suite) to cover all of the cases, or as an alternative you could integration test against [Moodle](https://moodle.org/) (free self-host, even has a [docker container](https://bitnami.com/stack/moodle) ready to go).